# loading data and replacement in R

Tags: r

Hi sorry first post here my apologies if I made a mistake.

So I'm fairly new to R and I was given an assignment where I am loading a CSV file into R.  When i read.csv the whole file I get a ton of blank spots where values should be.  The only info printed out is the N/A in the cells which is actually what I am trying to replace.

So I took a small sample of the file only the first couple rows and the info came up correctly in my read.csv comand.  My question is is the layout of the .csv too large to display the original data in my main.csv file?

Also, How would I go about replacing all the N/A and NA's in the file to change them to blank cells or ""

Sorry if i painted my scenario poorly

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: `read.csv` has an `na.strings` parameter (see `help("read.table")`). Use it. There is no such thing as "blank cells" in R. Missing values are encoded as `NA` and most R functions know how to handle missing values.

Answer (score -3):

first make sure that all of you data in the csv file is in GENERAL format!

there should be a title for each of the columns too

if you have an empty cell in your csv file then input a 0 into it

and make sure that around the data you CLEAR ALL the cells around them just incase there is anything funny in them

hope that helps if not then you could send me your file to sgreenaway@vmware.com and i will check it out for you :)

Comment: Do not put a 0 into empty cells unless you are absolutely sure that missing values must be 0, which is generally not the case.